# Baseline of vertically stacked elements

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

I have a container of vertically stacked elements.

```
<div>
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 2</div>
  <div>line 3</div>
  <div>line 4</div>
</div>
```

I want the baseline of the container to be identical to the baseline of a specific one of its elements, let's say the third one. It should look like this:

[image]

How can I do this with CSS?

As a related question, how is the baseline of such container of vertically stacked elements usually defined?

I want to give this container a property `display: inline-block`. This container appears next to other elements on a line, and I want them to be aligned according to the baseline.

Comment: Do the stacked elements have a known or predictable height?

Comment: @ChrisBaker No. Not in general.

Comment: I don't think this is doable with only CSS, then. Starred the question out of curiosity regarding the answers you get.

Comment: I know this is possible with TeX, and I have done a lot with it, but I don't know how to do it with CSS. I am willing to fully take the advantage of the newest CSS 3, if necessary.

Comment: it is possible, give me some time to find where it is..

Comment: Is it worth telling us your overall goal here (i.e., the use-case), in case there are alternative methods for tackling the problem?

Comment: Good follow-up, Michael -- can you take one step back in scope? It may open up some other possibilities. What effect will the baseline have on the layout of the parent element relative to it's siblings or the document?

Comment: Can the HTML be changed? If so, here is a rough solution: https://jsfiddle.net/ct0xbrqe/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This makes the baseline of the container coincide with the baseline of the third child `div`.

```
.container > div:nth-of-type(3) ~ div {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

**Examples:**

```css
.container {
  display: inline-block;
  background: yellow;
  padding: 0 0.5em;
  width: 8em;
}

.b1 > div:nth-of-type(1) ~ div {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.b2 > div:nth-of-type(2) ~ div {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.b3 > div:nth-of-type(3) ~ div {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.b4 > div:nth-of-type(4) ~ div {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(1) {
  font-size: 14px;
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(2) {
  font-size: 16px;
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(3) {
  font-size: 24px;
}

.container > div:nth-of-type(4) {
  font-size: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container b1">
  <div>baseline</div>
  <div>line 2</div>
  <div>line 3</div>
  <div>line 4</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<div class="container">
  consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container b2">
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>baseline</div>
  <div>line 3</div>
  <div>line 4</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<div class="container">
  consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
</div>
<hr>
<div class="container b3">
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 2</div>
  <div>baseline</div>
  <div>line 4</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<div class="container">
  consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
</div>

<hr>
<div class="container b4">
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 2</div>
  <div>line 3</div>
  <div>baseline</div>
</div>
<div class="container">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet
</div>
<div class="container">
  consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt
</div>
```

Comment: This looks perfect. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, something like this could work:

```css
body {
  line-height: 18px; /* set a line height and use it to calculate the offsets later */
}
div {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: baseline;

  background: black;
  color: white;   
}

div > div {
  display: block;
}

div.align-1 > div:nth-child(2) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -18px; /* 1 x line-height of parent */
}

div.align-1 > div:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -36px; /* 2 x line-height of parent */
}

div.align-1 > div:nth-child(4) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -54px; /* 3 x line-height of parent */
}

div.align-2 > div:nth-child(3) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -18px; /* 1 x line-height of parent */
}

div.align-2 > div:nth-child(4) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -36px; /* 2 x line-height  of parent */
}

div.align-3 > div:nth-child(4) {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: -18px; /* 1 x line-height  of parent */
}
```

```html
 Text
<div class="align-1">
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 2</div>
  <div>line 3</div>
  <div>line 4</div>
</div>
more text

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<hr />
<br> Text
<div class="align-2">
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 2</div>
  <div>line 3</div>
  <div>line 4</div>
</div>
more text

<br>
<br>
<br>
<hr />
<br> Text

<div class="align-3">
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 2</div>
  <div>line 3</div>
  <div>line 4</div>
</div>
more text

<br>
<br>
<hr />
<br> Text

<div class="align-4">
  <div>line 1</div>
  <div>line 2</div>
  <div>line 3</div>
  <div>line 4</div>
</div>
more text

<br>
<hr />
```

If you are using sass or less you could make it in a dynamic mixin that would work on variable element count.

Comment: Yes, that is the result I want, but the number of elements in a container is not predefined. This solution needs to set the maximum number of elements and define CSS classes accordingly.

Comment: @sawa that is true - unfortunately that's the most that can come out of my head at the moment. To have it work in any element count you would need to use js in this solution.